# How to fix Timeout exceeded error for async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to deploy a simple contract using mocha and ganache, but I got this error:
    Acontract
    1) "before each" hook for "Deploys a Contract"

```
0 passing (30s)
1 failing

1) "before each" hook for "Deploys a Contract":
Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure 
"done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The contract code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Acontract {

string public message; // new variable

function Acontract(string initialMessage) public {
    message = initialMessage;
}

function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
    message = newMessage;
}


}
```

The test file code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3'); 
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let result;

beforeEach( async () => {
 accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
.deploy ({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['WOW'] })
.send({  from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
});

describe('Acontract', ()=> {

  it('Deploys a Contract', async  ()=>{

console.log(result)

    });
});
```

How to solve this error, the code is simple, I tested getting accounts and it was ok, also deploy seems ok, when it comes to sending the code does not work! any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and fixed it like this: (**You may try number 2 first**).

1. Installed web3@1.0.0-beta.37 (**Note: your dependencies can be very different from mine as you are using solidity ^0.4.17**)

[image]

2. Added **ganache provider** in the code.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
//Ganache Provider
const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const { interface, bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let result;

beforeEach( async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy ({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['WOW'] })
        .send({  from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});

    //Set provider
    result.setProvider(provider);
});

describe('Acontract', ()=> {

    it('Deploys a Contract', async  ()=>{

        console.log(result)

    });
});
```

3. "Contract" object structure is changed a bit in this version. So, I had to update compile.js export a bit as well (**You may not need it with your version of solidity compiler**).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Md. Zubaer Ahammed, I fixed the issue by changing the web3 library version to web3@1.0.0-beta.37, and one important thing I noticed is that when I install web3 library there will be a vulnerability issue, if I apply audit fix, the error still exists even if web3@1.0.0-beta.37 was used, if I dont apply the audit fix, then the error is not there anymore.